Почему не выходит получить данные из context.user_data[]( получаю None) используя ConversationHandler в python-telegram-bot
недавно начал изучать python-telegram-bot. Смотря примеры в https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py было решено написать что-то своё, вот что получилось:
import re

from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
Application,
MessageHandler,
filters,
CallbackQueryHandler,
ConversationHandler,
ContextTypes,
CallbackContext,
)
from text_const import *
from utils.helpers import *


user_data = {}
FULLNAME, EMAIL, NOTES, COMPANIES = range(4)

async def cancel_deal(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  await update.message.reply_text("Bye!")
  return ConversationHandler.END


async def request_fullname_for_deal_handle(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_NOTES_WHEN_AUTH,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return FULLNAME


async def first_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  if answer.lower() in [CANCEL_HANDLE]:
      await cancel_deal(update, context) 
      return ConversationHandler.END   
  elif len(answer.split()) != 3:
      await update.message.reply_text(NOT_CORRECT_FIO_STATE_TO_DEAL,
            parse_mode='HTML')
      return FULLNAME

  context.user_data['fullname'] = f'{answer}'
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_EMAIL,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return EMAIL


async def second_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  email = answer.strip()
  if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):
      await update.message.reply_text(NOT_CORRECT_EMAIL_STATE_TO_DEAL,
              parse_mode='HTML')
      return EMAIL

  context.user_data['email'] = f'{answer}'
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_NOTES,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return NOTES


async def third_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  context.user_data['notes'] = f'{answer}'
  db = await init_firebase()
  companies_ref = db.collection("comp").stream()
  inline_keyboard, callback_data_list = await create_inline_keyboard(comp_ref)

  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_CHOICE_COMPANY_AUTH,
            parse_mode='HTML', 
            reply_markup=inline_keyboard)

  print(f"fio after input: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}")
  print(f"email after input: {context.user_data.get('email')}")
  print(f"Notes after input: {context.user_data.get('notes')}")
  return COMPANIES


async def fourth_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    
  db = await init_firebase()
  company_ref = db.collection("comp").document(update.callback_query.data)


  client_ref = db.collection("client").where("telegram_id", "==", update.callback_query.message.chat.id).stream()
    for client in client_ref:
        if client.to_dict().get('tenant_id').id == update.callback_query.data:
            pass
        else:
            context.user_data["comp"] = company_ref
            
  else:
    context.user_data["comp"] = company_ref

  col_ref = db.collection("crm").where("tenant", "==", comp_ref).stream()

  # Format the output
  companies_info = f"Companies: {context.user_data.get('companies')}"
  notes_info = f"Notes: {context.user_data.get('notes')}"
  notess_info = f"fio: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}"
  notesss_info = f"email: {context.user_data.get('email')}"

  # Collecting CRM settings information
  crm_settings_info = "CRM Settings:\n"
  for doc in col_ref:
    crm_settings_info += f"- {doc.id}: {doc.to_dict()}\n"

  # Combine all information into a single message
  final_message = f"{notes_info}\n{companies_info}\n{crm_settings_info}\n{notess_info}\n{notesss_info}"

  await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(final_message)
  return ConversationHandler.END


 # FSM
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points= 
[MessageHandler(filters.Regex(f"^{REQUEST_FULLNAME_FOR_DEAL_HANDLE}$"), request_fullname_for_deal_handle)],
    states={
        FULLNAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, first_response)],
        EMAIL: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, second_response)],
        NOTES: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, third_response)],
        COMPANIES: [CallbackQueryHandler(fourth_response)]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Regex(f"^{CANCEL_HANDLE}$"), cancel_deal)]
)

Извините, что внёс однотипные функ в код.
В данных строках:
 print(f"fio after input: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}")
 print(f"email after input: {context.user_data.get('email')}")
 print(f"Notes after input: {context.user_data.get('notes')}")

Получаем такой ответ:
fio after input: None # test test test
email after input: None # test@test.test
Notes after input: test # test

Я воожу всегда test , однако получаю None
При получении callbackquery, последнего state, получаю сообщение от бота:
Notes: None
Companies: <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 
  ...>
CRM Settings:
- ...: {'tenant': 
  <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at ...>, 
  'col': []}

fio: None
email: None

Почему не выходит корректно получить context.user_data[] в следующем состоянии или по выходу из него?

на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

@Akina спасибо, сейчас исправлю
